# Operator algebra in integral form

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

In QM courses one can quite often see expressions like:

$ \langle x| \hat{p} | \psi \rangle = \int dp \langle x| \hat{p} |p\rangle \langle p| \psi \rangle  $

but I'm a bit confused as to how it works. I know that

$ I = \int dp |p\rangle \langle p|$

but how does all the rest get under the integral? Or how does $|p\rangle \langle p|$ end up past $\langle x| \hat{p} |$?

Comment: "all the rest" doesn't depend on $p$ (the variable that is being integrated, in the sense that the rest is *not* a function of it), so you can move it whereever you want.

Comment: So I couldn't pull off the same trick with identity operator formed with $x$s? @ACuriousMind

Comment: You can't introduce an integration over $x$ because there is already an $x$ present. You could do the same by introducing *another* position variable $x'$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In QM courses one can quite often see expressions like:
>
> $ \langle x| \hat{p} | \psi \rangle = \int dp \langle x| \hat{p}
> > |p\rangle \langle p| \psi \rangle  $
>
> but I'm a bit confused as to how it works. I know that
>
> $ I = \int dp |p\rangle \langle p|$
>
> but how does all the rest get under the integral? Or how does
>   $|p\rangle \langle p|$ end up past $\langle x| \hat{p} |$?

$$
\langle x| \hat{p} | \psi \rangle = \langle x| \hat{p} I| \psi \rangle = \langle x| \hat{p} \int dp |p\rangle \langle p|| \psi \rangle
$$

The $\int dp$ is just a number and can move past the operator. Despite the horrible notation the operator $\hat p$ does not depend on $p$, so it can also move underneath the integral. So
$$
\langle x| \hat{p} \int dp |p\rangle \langle p| \psi \rangle
=
\int dp\langle x| \hat{p} |p\rangle \langle p| \psi \rangle
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you have a matrix equation $$BC = CB$$ then $$BIC = CB$$ so if $$AA^{-1} = I$$ we have  $$BAA^{-1}C = CB$$ This is true even if the matrix A does not commute with the matrices B and C. In much the same way we can insert the identity operator before the psi wave function then substitute in your identity and obtain the result you require.

Comment: I think the question was about how to pull the integral to the left and leave the rest to the right of the x.